# How to start a rebar application twice or more with different names?

Tags: erlang, rebar, reltool

I have a rebar application called pingpong. After `rebar generate` I start the packaged application using `./rel/pingpong/bin/pingpong start`. The problem is that the erlang VM always has the name `-name pingpong@127.0.0.1` but what I want is to start the application once with the name `ping@127.0.0.1` and then again with the name `pong@127.0.0.1`.

I know that the name stays in ./rel/pingpong/releases/VSN/vm.config but I don't want to manually edit the file before starting the application. I want something like `pingpong start -name=ping`. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can edit the bin/pingpong script to something like thist:

Instead of

```
NAME_ARG=`egrep -e '^-s?name' $RUNNER_ETC_DIR/vm.args`
```

set:

```
NAME_ARG=${NAME_ARG:-`egrep -e '^-s?name' $RUNNER_ETC_DIR/vm.args`}
```

in this way you will be able to override node name from the command line:

```
NAME_ARG="-name myname@localhost" bin/pingpong start
```

For console/start command:

Find a line in yout startup script:

```
CMD="$BINDIR/erlexec -boot $RUNNER_BASE_DIR/releases/$APP_VSN/$BOOTFILE -mode embedded -config $CONFIG_PATH -args_file $VMARGS_PATH"
```

Add $NAME_ARG at the end:

```
 CMD="$BINDIR/erlexec -boot $RUNNER_BASE_DIR/releases/$APP_VSN/$BOOTFILE -mode embedded -config $CONFIG_PATH -args_file $VMARGS_PATH $NAME_ARG"
```

And don't forget to remove -name NAME from your .args files

Comment: It doesn't work. NAME_ARG is used only for `stop`, `restart`, `attach`. But for `start` or `console` the name from vm.args is used and NAME_ARG is ignored.